# Screen Sharing app does not save connections where IP is the same and ports are different

Tags: screen-sharing

I'm trying to save multiple connections to different Mac machines available in cloud where the IP is the same but the ports are different.

```
XXX.XX.XX.XXX:PORT_1
XXX.XX.XX.XXX:PORT_2
XXX.XX.XX.XXX:PORT_3
```

Screen Sharing app just save one connection at the time. So, if I open the first one, it saves it in the correct way. When I open the second one, the one that has been saved previously is overridden.

Is there any way to force the behavior of Screen Sharing app?

Comment: Is this the native screen-sharing app or a different one?

Comment: The Mac one @Allan. Thanks Lorenzo

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t test at the moment, but if I remember correctly, it uses the IP address or FDQN (fully qualified domain name - foo.bar.com) as the name of the connection.  It’s a limitation of the app

Comment: @Allan Thank you very much.

Comment: Under the Finder, you can select "Connect to Server". On the popup, you can save the same the same IP address with a different port multiple times to the list. For example: `vnc://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:PORT_1` and `vnc://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:PORT_2`. When selecting from the list, the Screen Sharing application is automatically launched.